# Google Closure Compiler API returns nothing

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

This is the piece of code that is causing trouble when passed to the Google Closure Compiler API (it just returns nothing, whatever code I add to this part). Anyone sees what I don't? Non-minimized code is functioning as expected.

```
window.myFun = function(data){
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var object = {int_id:data[i]["id"], str_value:data[i]["val"]};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www.example.com/webservice",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: object,
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);   
        },
        error: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
};
```

Comment: Never mind, I've found the problem. There was an earlier problem which I suspected to be caused by comments, so I manipulated lines with // in them (which of course can also be a url)..

Comment: This may happens because you did not wrap the `object` keys with double quote (`int_id`, `str_value `), closure compiler will rename these variables